# Theano tensor slicing... how to use boolean to slice?

Tags: arrays, numpy, slice, theano

In numpy, if I have a boolean array, I can use it to select elements of another array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> idx = np.array([True, False, True])
>>> x[idx] 
array([1, 3])
```

I need to do this in theano. This is what I tried, but I got an unexpected result.

```
>>> from theano import tensor as T
>>> x = T.vector()
>>> idx = T.ivector()
>>> y = x[idx]
>>> y.eval({x: np.array([1,2,3]), idx: np.array([True, False, True])})
array([ 2.,  1.,  2.])
```

Can someone explain the theano result and suggest how to get the numpy result? I need to know how to do this in order to properly instantiate a 'givens' argument in a theano function declaration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You got `[2, 1, 2]` because `[True, False, True]` was interpreted as `[0, 1, 0]`

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean: [True, False, True] evaluates to [1,0,1]. Do you know how to get it to evaluate to the numpy result? Is there any way to do boolean slicing like numpy?

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant, with the 0s and 1s swapped. See my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [not supported](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#indexing) in theano:

> We do not support boolean masks, as Theano does not have a boolean type (we use int8 for the output of logic operators).
>
> Theano indexing with a “mask” (incorrect approach):
>
> ```
> >>> t = theano.tensor.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
> >>> t[t > 4].eval()  # an array with shape (3, 3, 3)
> ...
> ```
>
> Getting a Theano result like NumPy:
>
> ```
> >>> t[(t > 4).nonzero()].eval()
> array([5, 6, 7, 8])
> ```

So you need `y = x[idx.nonzero()]`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. =)

Comment: Was stuck on this for hours. Thank you so much. The Theano documentation for `T.nonzero` [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html) on this is *empty*!

Comment: @user27886: `T.nonzero` is the same as [`np.nonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero), which is documented

Comment: And the numpy docs on [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) explain how boolean indexing translates to `.nonzero`

Comment: @Eric do you know how could I find the source code of theano implementing integer array indexing ? I'm particularly interested in GPU array indexing support (It will probably be cuda code)