# Tilted loss in theano

Tags: python, theano, keras

I am trying to calculate the tilted loss, which in turn will be used in Keras. However, I must be doing something wrong since I am getting negative loss values (which ought to be impossible). Can anyone point out what I've done wrong. I'm assuming it's the theano syntax that I have got wrong.

The loss is defined mathematically as:
[image]
where $\xi_i = y_i - f_i$ where $y_i$ is the observation and $f_i$ is the prediction. Furthermore I am after the mean loss, thus I have defined my loss function as:

```
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{\alpha\sum \xi_i-\sum I(\xi_i<0)\xi_i}{N}
$$
```

where $I()$ is the indicator function and takes on the values 1 if true.

Hence my loss function is defined as follows:

```
def tilted_loss2(y,f):
    q = 0.05
    e = (y-f)
    return (q*tt.sum(e)-tt.sum(e[e<0]))/e.shape[0]
```

however, when I run my network I get negative values. Is there something wrong with the theano syntax here? my biggest suspicion is here: `tt.sum(e[e<0]))`. Can you slice it like this?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not slice like this. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425401/theano-tensor-slicing-how-to-use-boolean-to-slice/37425475#37425475)

You need to change your loss function as follows:

```
def tilted_loss2(y,f):
    q = 0.05
    e = (y-f)
    return (q*tt.sum(e)-tt.sum(e[(e<0).nonzero()]))/e.shape[0]
```

You can also try this work-around using `abs` function instead of complex slicing syntax that might not work:

```
def tilted_loss2(y,f):
    q = 0.05
    e = (y-f)
    return (q*tt.sum(e)-tt.sum(e-abs(e))/2.)/e.shape[0]
```